# Ggplot box plot draws only points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm an R newbie and am trying to draw a boxplot representing the number of variables per user with the following data using ggplot.

```
'data.frame':   14443 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ id: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ variable   : num  3 22 23 8 ...
```

I've tried both:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x="", y = variable)) +
geom_boxplot()
```

and:

```
ggplot(df) +
geom_boxplot(aes(x = "", y = variable))
```

But, rather than drawing a nice box plot, I get a collection of points like the picture below.

I feel like I am probably making a very silly mistake but can't find it. Can anyone help?

[image: Failed Box Plot]

Comment: please add a reproducible small example, then it is easier for everyone to help you.

Comment: This is likely an issue with your data. I don't see nothing wrong with the code per se. If you provide us with a snapshot of your data (using `dput`), we might be able to help

Comment: I suspect that most of your data points are in the small window of 0 to ~5, you see the 'box' at the very bottom of your picture. Everything above are 'outliers' and get plottet as points. Try adding `+ scale_y_log10()` to your plot and see what happens.

Comment: It is likely you have an excess of zeroes in your data, so that all non-zero observations are treated as outliers in the boxplot visualisation.

Comment: Actually, @tifu 's reponse has helped me resolve this! On a closer look at the data, I realised that most of the values are 1. So the box plot was drawn correctly, it is just all scrunched up at the bottom. Newbie error - apologies for any inconvenience, and thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, just seen @hdkrgr 's response which helps resolve - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documenting the answer that came out of the comments.

As most of the values in the dataset were 1, the boxplot was all scrunched up at the bottom. Adding this to the bottom changed the perspective of the plot and solved the problem.

```
scale_y_log10()
```

Shout out to @tifu and @hdkrgr for helping with this.